# iPhone Deep Linking to Amazon Application / URI Scheme

Tags: iphone, deep-linking

Searched the net a bit, can not seem to find the syntax on iOS for deep linking (Scheme) to display a product in the native app.

Anyone have the syntax for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Amazon URI / Scheme for iOS according to reply email from Amazon.